# Prove $|B_i \Delta B_j|\le 2$ without coding theory or other overkills

Tags: combinatorics

$A=\{0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9\}$, and $B_1, B_2,... B_{100}$ are arbitrary subsets of $A$.

Prove that there exist at least two subsets $B_i$ and $B_j$ such as $|B_i \Delta B_j|\le2$ **without using coding theory**

Note: this question is asked in [Prove that cardinality of the symmetric difference of subsets less than 3](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/700138/prove-that-cardinality-of-the-symmetric-difference-of-subsets-less-than-3), **but** the accepted solution is an **overkill**. The challenge is to revisit the problem and come up with something **more elegant**

**Attempt**

I started with proof by contradiction aiming at pigeon hole at some point. I tried to split all subsets of $A$ by number of elements $(0, 1,..., 10)$ and find the max number of subsets from each group. The goal is to show that from all $11$ groups the sum of max numbers of subsets is less than $100$ in this case. But I got stuck

Comment: Why do you think it's an overkill? Linear algebra methods in combinatorics are a very well established and powerful tool that is often hard to replace with "elementary" arguments.

Comment: This is one of introductory problems of an exam, and the level of difficulty of other intro questions suggests there should be a simpler approach. Command of coding theory is not a prerequisite in this exam

Answer (score 2):

For each $i\in \{1,\dots,100\}$, let
$$
S_i=\Big\{B_i,B_i\Delta\{0\},B_i\Delta\{1\},\dots,B_i\Delta\{8\},B_i\Delta\{9\}\Big\}
$$
That is, $S_i$ is the set of sets whose symmetric difference with $B_i$ has zero or one elements, or the set of sets which can be obtained from $B_i$ by adding/removing at most one element.

If it were true that $|B_i\Delta B_j|> 2$ for each $i,j$, then the sets $S_i$ would be pairwise disjoint. Indeed, if $C\in S_i\cap S_j$, then you could obtain $B_i$ from $B_j$ by adding/removing at most one element from $B_j$ to get $C$, then adding/removing at most one element from $C$ to get $B_i$, implying $|B_i\Delta B_j|\le 2$.

But you cannot have $100$ pairwise disjoint subsets of the power set of $\{0,1,\dots,9\}$ with $11$ elements each, because $100\cdot 11> 2^{10}$. Contradiction!

Comment: Basicly you defined a graph with $2^{10}$ vertices where two set are connected iff $|A\Delta B|=1$? And $S_i$ is closed set of adjacent vertices to $B_i$.

Comment: @Aqua That's right. $|A\Delta B|\le 2$ is equivalent to the distance of $A$ and $B$ in the graph being at most $2$.